# Open Facebook app with text from iPad app

Tags: ios, facebook

Unless I integrate the Facebook API to my iOS app, I share some text opening the Facebook native app with this command you can see here:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                       [self.txtAdreca.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fb://publish/profile/me?text=%@",urlString];
BOOL canOpenURL = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:post]];
if (canOpenURL) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:post]];
}
```

It works correctly from my iPhone app, but not in iPad. In iPad it only opens the Facebook app but not with the text written as in the iPhone case.